# Graph Layout : re-layout preserving the shape of the drawing

Tags: java, javascript, algorithm, graph, graph-layout

I'd like to draw a **graph** composed of nodes and edges, using a **spring layout algorithm** (a kind of force directed layout)
Once the graph is laid out, I'd like to let the user interactively add new nodes, and **let the layout evolve**, i.e. positioning the new nodes while maintaining the previous "shape" (not moving the already positioned nodes too much).

I mean something like what **WordVis** is doing at http://www.wordvis.com.

I'm currently using the spring layouter available in the [GraphDracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/) library. It's a "simple" one, meaning that if you re-layout the graph, you may get a completely different layout (this is due, I think, to the calls to `Math.rand` in the algorithm)

**What is the algorithm/strategy to do what I'd like to do?**

I see that the graphdracula's layouter sets the initial node pos to zero, and then iterates to calculate the final nodes' positions.
Suppose I add a set of nodes `newNodes` adjacent to an `expandedNode`: to maintain the existing shape, is it enough to set the initial pos of each of the `newNodes` to the one of `expandedNode` and then apply the forces to the all of the nodes once again?

**Do you have any pointer to an algorithm that not only lays out the graph once, but also lets you add new nodes re-layouting the whole graph without changing the drawing too much?**

Any hint is welcome.

I'm currently working with javascript, but the language is not important.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) for that:

1. Import your graph
2. In Layouts panel, render your graph with ForceAtlas then stop the layout.
3. Select all nodes, right-click and "Settle" the nodes. They won't move.
4. Add new nodes and links.
5. Run the same layout again.

Of course it's not a perfect solution but this trick will work reasonably if not adding too much new nodes that connect different regions of the graph.